# Google sheet - Value is not being set correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have setup a google sheet with a script attached to it that runs a function to pull chromebook device information, works great apart from two fields im interested in, "cpuStatusReports" and "diskVolumeReports" the script logger does show the correct info but my sheet cell values is set to for example

> {cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo=[Ljava.lang.Object;@d151552,
>   cpuTemperatureInfo=[Ljava.lang.Object;@f57094c,
>   reportTime=2019-03-29T18:15:56.049Z}

my function is :-

> function chromebookdetails2() { var domain, chromebooks, page, ss,
>   sheet, pageToken, i var sheetData4 =
>   onSheet.getSheetByName("chromebook") //sheetData4.clear(); domain =
>   "mydomainnamehere" chromebooks= new Array() do{ page =
>   AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list("my_customer", {domain: domain,
>   maxResults: 1000, pageToken: pageToken })  for (i in
>   page.chromeosdevices){ chromebooks.push(page.chromeosdevices[i]) }
>   pageToken = page.nextPageToken }while(pageToken){ var row = 3
>   //starting row position for (var i = 0; i < chromebooks.length; i++) {
>   var sheetData4 = onSheet.getSheetByName("chromebook") 
>   /////////////////////Header////////////////////////////////////////
>   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
>   sheetData4.getRange(1,1).setValue("Date Ran - "+date); //(2,1 means
>   2nd row, 1st column) sheetData4.getRange(2,1).setValue("orgUnitPath");
>   //(2,1 means 2nd row, 1st column)
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,2).setValue("annotatedUser");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,3).setValue("annotatedLocation");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,4).setValue("annotatedAssetId");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,5).setValue("serialNumber");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,6).setValue("lastEnrollmentTime");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,7).setValue("deviceId");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,8).setValue("bootMode");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,9).setValue("recentUsers");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,10).setValue("macAddress");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,11).setValue("lastSync");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,12).setValue("osVersion");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,13).setValue("platformVersion");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,14).setValue("activeTimeRanges");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,15).setValue("model");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,16).setValue("etag");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,17).setValue("firmwareVersion");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,18).setValue("status");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,19).setValue("ethernetMacAddress");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,20).setValue("notes"); 
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,21).setValue("systemRamTotal");
>   sheetData4.getRange(2,22).setValue("CPU");
>
> if(chromebooks[i].length == 0){
>       // array is empty  Logger.log('empty');     } else { //array not empty >Logger.log('not empty');
>
> Logger.log(chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports);
>   /////////////////////Array Data///////////////////////////////////
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,1).setValue(chromebooks[i].orgUnitPath);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,2).setValue(chromebooks[i].annotatedUser);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,3).setValue(chromebooks[i].annotatedLocation);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,4).setValue(chromebooks[i].annotatedAssetId);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,5).setValue(chromebooks[i].serialNumber);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,6).setValue(chromebooks[i].lastEnrollmentTime);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,7).setValue(chromebooks[i].deviceId);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,8).setValue(chromebooks[i].bootMode);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,9).setValue(chromebooks[i].recentUsers);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,10).setValue(chromebooks[i].macAddress);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,11).setValue(chromebooks[i].lastSync);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,12).setValue(chromebooks[i].osVersion);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,13).setValue(chromebooks[i].platformVersion);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,14).setValue(chromebooks[i].activeTimeRanges);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,15).setValue(chromebooks[i].model);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,16).setValue(chromebooks[i].etag);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,17).setValue(chromebooks[i].firmwareVersion);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,18).setValue(chromebooks[i].status);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,19).setValue(chromebooks[i].ethernetMacAddress);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,20).setValue(chromebooks[i].notes);
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,21).setValue(chromebooks[i].systemRamTotal /
>   (1024*1024) /1024); // "/ (1024*1024)" converts bytes to Mb "/1024"
>   then converts back to Gb
>   sheetData4.getRange(row,22).setValue(chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports);
>
> }
>
> row++ Logger.log(row) } } }

The results in the log file....

> [{cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo=[63],
>   cpuTemperatureInfo=[{temperature=24, label=soc_dts0 },
>   {temperature=24, label=soc_dts1 }],
>   reportTime=2019-03-10T18:11:49.480Z}]

How do i reference cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo, cpuTemperatureInfo from cpuStatusReports?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

In the loop add

```
var status = chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports;
var cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo = status[0].cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo[0];
var cpuTemperatureInfo = status[0].cpuTemperatureInfo[0].temperature;
var label = status[0].cpuTemperatureInfo[0].label;
```

Check logger.log() to see if you get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for replying...unfortunatley i get a "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

Comment: Is chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports json ? If so, try to wrap it in JSON.parse(chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports).

Comment: I'm not entirley sure if it is JSON or not, the data recieved back from Logger.log() doesnt seem to be in a JSON format, trying to parse in JSON i get an error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property "cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo" from undefined....

Comment: If i comment everything out apart from 
var status = JSON.parse(chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports);
I get "SyntaxError: Expected end of stream at char 166" error... if i look at the log i get - "{cpuUtilizationPercentageInfo=[35, 30, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 15, 3], cpuTemperatureInfo=[{temperature=36, label=iwlwifi
}], reportTime=2019-05-22T02:26:15.014Z}]"

Answer (score 0):

did you tried:

```
 .setValue(chromebooks[i].cpuStatusReports.toString());
```

just turn every thing into string and you should have no problem on setValue() I guess.